# FSM is double incrementing

Tags: verilog

I have a newbie FSM Verilog question.  In the below code, around line 96, I am incrementing led_num with the non blocking led_num <= led_num+1;  However, because of the way my code is setup I have a non blocking curr_state <= next_state at line 82, and then I am doing a next_state <= "NEXT STATE" in every one of my case statements.  This is causing me to be in each state 2 clocks and is causing my led_num <= led_num+1 to execute twice, and I want just a single time.

How do I go about fixing this so I am in each state a single clock or how do I prevent the led_num being incremented by two each time?  I had one person tell me to non blocking all of the time, but some examples mix them and I am pretty sure I need to move my nextState to use a blocking assignment but I have tried several things so far and I keep messing it up.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module ws2812_b(clk, rst, send_the_data, led_data_out);
    input clk;
    input rst;
    input send_the_data;
    output reg led_data_out; 

    
parameter NUMBER_LEDS = 5;    
parameter ADDRESS_BITS =8;
parameter  NUM_BITS = 24;
parameter  STATE_BITS = 4;    

parameter T0_HIGH_0_COUNT = 6;    // .35us  (System clock = 12Mhz, 83.3 ns/cycle.  
parameter T0_HIGH_1_COUNT = 16;   // .9us
parameter CYCLE_COUNT = (T0_HIGH_0_COUNT+T0_HIGH_1_COUNT);  //.9+.35
parameter RESET_COUNT = 1500;    // 50us  
    
localparam  ST_IDLE = 4'd0,
            ST_GET_WORD = 4'd1,
            ST_SEND_START = 4'd2,
            ST_UPDATE_WORD = 4'd3,
            ST_DELAY_0 = 4'd4,
            ST_DRIVE_0 = 4'd5,
            ST_DELAY_1 = 4'd6,
            ST_CHECK_WORD_DONE = 4'd7,
            ST_SEND_RESET = 4'd8,            
            ST_NDEF_9 = 4'd9, 
            ST_NDEF_10 = 4'd10,
            ST_NDEF_11 = 4'd11,            
            ST_DELAY_1S = 4'd12,
            ST_NDEF_13 = 4'd13,
            ST_NDEF_14 = 4'd14,            
            ST_NDEF_15 = 4'd15;            
reg [STATE_BITS-1:0]currState;
reg [STATE_BITS-1:0]nextState;
reg [14:0] delay_value;
reg [NUM_BITS-1:0] led_word;

reg [5:0] bit_num;
reg [13:0] delay0, delay1;
reg [8:0] led_num;
`define rundelay  currState <= ST_DELAY_1S
`define returndelay currState <= nextState


always @(posedge clk, posedge rst)
    begin
        if (rst) begin
            currState <= ST_IDLE;
            nextState <= ST_IDLE;
            led_data_out <=0;
            led_word <= 0; 
            bit_num <= 0;   
            delay0 <= 0;
            delay1 <=0;
            delay_value <=0;
            led_num <= 0;
            end
        else
            begin
                currState <= nextState;
                case (currState)
                    ST_IDLE:  //0
                        begin
                        led_data_out <= 0;
                        nextState    <= ST_GET_WORD;
                        led_num      <= 0;
                        end

                    ST_GET_WORD:  //1 
                        begin
                            led_word  <= 24'h335599; 
                            bit_num   <= 0;   
                            nextState <= ST_SEND_START;
                            led_num   <= led_num + 1 ;     // ***** DOUBLE INCREMENTS ****
                        end

                      ST_SEND_START:  //2
                        begin

                            led_data_out <= 1;
                            if (led_word[0]==1) 
                                begin
                                    delay0 <= T0_HIGH_1_COUNT;
                                    delay1 <= (CYCLE_COUNT - T0_HIGH_1_COUNT + 1);                                      
                                end else
                                begin
                                    delay0 <= T0_HIGH_0_COUNT;
                                    delay1 <= (CYCLE_COUNT - T0_HIGH_0_COUNT + 1);                                      
                                end
                            nextState <= ST_UPDATE_WORD;    
                        end
                      
                        ST_UPDATE_WORD:  //3
                            begin
                            led_word[23:0] <= {1'b0,led_word[23:1]};
                            bit_num <= bit_num+1;
                            nextState <= ST_DRIVE_0;
                            delay_value <= delay0;
                            `rundelay;  
                            end

                        ST_DRIVE_0:  //5
                            begin
                            led_data_out <= 0;
                            nextState    <= ST_CHECK_WORD_DONE;
                            delay_value  <= delay1;
                            `rundelay;  
                            end

                        ST_CHECK_WORD_DONE:  //4
                            begin
                            if (bit_num<24) 
                                begin
                                   nextState <=  ST_SEND_START;
                                end else
                                begin
                                    if (led_num<3)
                                    begin
                                        nextState <= ST_GET_WORD;
                                    end else
                                    begin 
                                        nextState <= ST_SEND_RESET;
                                    end
                                end
                            end
                            
                        ST_SEND_RESET:
                            begin
                            led_data_out <= 0;
                            nextState <= ST_IDLE;
                            delay_value <= 2000;
                            `rundelay;  
                            end               
                            
                    ST_DELAY_1S:    // Delay of ~1sec. Note that the total delay is one clock cycle more because of the state transition.
                        begin
                            if (delay_value)
                                begin
                                    delay_value <= delay_value -1;      // as long as delay_value is larger than zero ( bitwise or)
                                                                        // decrement (decrementing counters synthesize smaller than
                                                                        // incrementing counters as no comparator is needed, only a
                                                                        // zero check which is a bitwise or.
                                    currState <= currState;
                                
                                end
                            else
                                begin
                                    //currState <= nextState;               // if it hits zero ; throw the target state into currentstate.
                                    `returndelay;
                                end
                        end
                   default:
                   begin
                        currState <= ST_IDLE;
                   end         
                  endcase
            end
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: you realize that there are no line numbers in this coed? which is line 96? 82? In general, your state-machine is a mess with 'random' use of currState and a nextState as an output.  Usual way of organizing the machine is to calculate the **next state** which becomes *current* at the next clock cycle only. I suggest you rethink the way you implemented it.

Comment: It is unusual to have nextState and currentState both be flops. In a single always block strategy, having only state is enough (i.e. no nextState). In a two always block strategy, currentState is synchronous (assigned to nextState) and nextState is in a separate combinational always block.

Answer (score -1):

As Greg pointed out, FSMs are implemented one of two ways:

1. Single always block (like you've implemented)  In this case, every clock runs through the "always block" once and you only need one "State" variable.  All variables are "non-blocking" ("<=" symbol) which implies that all statements are executed in parallel.
2. Double always blocks.  In this case, the first always block is purely combinational, which is fully "blocking" assigns so that you can have sequential arithmetic to calcuate your final value.  The second always block behaves like a set of registers to let the whole state-machine "step" to the next state on the clock edge.  This setup requires "currState" and "nextState".  The first combinational always block calculates "nextState" from "currState".  The second (sequential) always  block simply transfers nextState to currState on a clock edge.

In your case, it looks like you're trying to jump to a "delay" state for a certain number of cycles and then jump back to the next state in the sequence like a subroutine in C code that delays.

While I haven't run it, I think the following is closer to what you're trying to do.  When you jump to ST_DELAY_1S, you need to save the state you want to return to in a separate variable (I used afterDelayState) so that you can spin in the delay state and then return (much like the instruction pointer on the stack) to the proper place.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module ws2812_b(clk, rst, send_the_data, led_data_out);
   input clk;
   input rst;
   input send_the_data;
   output reg led_data_out; 

   
   parameter NUMBER_LEDS = 5;    
   parameter ADDRESS_BITS =8;
   parameter  NUM_BITS = 24;
   parameter  STATE_BITS = 4;    

   parameter T0_HIGH_0_COUNT = 6;    // .35us  (System clock = 12Mhz, 83.3 ns/cycle.  
   parameter T0_HIGH_1_COUNT = 16;   // .9us
   parameter CYCLE_COUNT = (T0_HIGH_0_COUNT+T0_HIGH_1_COUNT);  //.9+.35
   parameter RESET_COUNT = 1500;    // 50us  
   
   localparam  ST_IDLE = 4'd0,
     ST_GET_WORD = 4'd1,
     ST_SEND_START = 4'd2,
     ST_UPDATE_WORD = 4'd3,
     ST_DELAY_0 = 4'd4,
     ST_DRIVE_0 = 4'd5,
     ST_DELAY_1 = 4'd6,
     ST_CHECK_WORD_DONE = 4'd7,
     ST_SEND_RESET = 4'd8,            
     ST_NDEF_9 = 4'd9, 
     ST_NDEF_10 = 4'd10,
     ST_NDEF_11 = 4'd11,            
     ST_DELAY_1S = 4'd12,
     ST_NDEF_13 = 4'd13,
     ST_NDEF_14 = 4'd14,            
     ST_NDEF_15 = 4'd15;            
   reg [STATE_BITS-1:0] State;
   reg [STATE_BITS-1:0] afterDelayState;
   reg [14:0]           delay_value;
   reg [NUM_BITS-1:0]   led_word;

   reg [5:0]            bit_num;
   reg [13:0]           delay0, delay1;
   reg [8:0]            led_num;
//`define rundelay  currState <= ST_DELAY_1S
//`define returndelay currState <= nextState


   always @(posedge clk, posedge rst)
     begin
        if (rst) begin
           State <= ST_IDLE;
           afterDelayState <= ST_IDLE;
           led_data_out <=0;
           led_word <= 0; 
           bit_num <= 0;   
           delay0 <= 0;
           delay1 <=0;
           delay_value <=0;
           led_num <= 0;
        end
        else
          begin
             case (State)
               ST_IDLE:  //0
                 begin
                    led_data_out <= 0;
                    State    <= ST_GET_WORD;
                    led_num      <= 0;
                 end

               ST_GET_WORD:  //1 
                 begin
                    led_word  <= 24'h335599; 
                    bit_num   <= 0;   
                    State <= ST_SEND_START;
                    led_num   <= led_num + 1 ;     // ***** DOUBLE INCREMENTS ****
                 end

               ST_SEND_START:  //2
                 begin

                    led_data_out <= 1;
                    if (led_word[0]==1) 
                      begin
                         delay0 <= T0_HIGH_1_COUNT;
                         delay1 <= (CYCLE_COUNT - T0_HIGH_1_COUNT + 1);                                      
                      end else
                        begin
                           delay0 <= T0_HIGH_0_COUNT;
                           delay1 <= (CYCLE_COUNT - T0_HIGH_0_COUNT + 1);                                      
                        end
                    State <= ST_UPDATE_WORD;    
                 end
               
               ST_UPDATE_WORD:  //3
                 begin
                    led_word[23:0] <= {1'b0,led_word[23:1]};
                    bit_num <= bit_num+1;
                    State <= ST_DRIVE_0;
                    delay_value <= delay0;
                    // delay "delay0" cycles and then jump to ST_DRIVE_0
                    delay_value  <= delay0;
                    State <= ST_DELAY_1S;
                    afterDelayState    <= ST_DRIVE_0;
                 end

               ST_DRIVE_0:  //5
                 begin
                    led_data_out <= 0;
                    // delay "delay1" cycles and then jump to ST_CHECK_WORD_DONE
                    delay_value  <= delay1;
                    State <= ST_DELAY_1S;
                    afterDelayState    <= ST_CHECK_WORD_DONE;
                 end

               ST_CHECK_WORD_DONE:  //4
                 begin
                    if (bit_num<24) 
                      begin
                         State <=  ST_SEND_START;
                      end else
                        begin
                           if (led_num<3)
                             begin
                                State <= ST_GET_WORD;
                             end else
                               begin 
                                  State <= ST_SEND_RESET;
                               end
                        end
                 end
               
               ST_SEND_RESET:
                 begin
                    led_data_out <= 0;
                    // delay 2000 cycles and then jump to ST_IDLE
                    delay_value <= 2000;
                    State <= ST_DELAY_1S;
                    afterDelayState <= ST_IDLE;
                 end               
               
               // This is a special "delay" loop that jumps to a specified "afterDelayState" when the delay_value runs to zero
               ST_DELAY_1S:    // Delay of ~1sec. Note that the total delay is one clock cycle more because of the state transition.
                 begin
                    if (delay_value)
                      begin
                         // every clock cycle stay in the ST_DELAY_1S state until the "delay_value" runs to zero
                         delay_value <= delay_value -1;      // as long as delay_value is larger than zero ( bitwise or)
                         // decrement (decrementing counters synthesize smaller than
                         // incrementing counters as no comparator is needed, only a
                         // zero check which is a bitwise or.
                         //
                         // no change in State, so we stay here
                         // State <= State
                      end
                    else
                      begin
                         //after it hits zero, jump to the state we stored in afterDelayState
                         State <= afterDelayState;
                      end
                 end
               default:
                 begin
                    State <= ST_IDLE;
                 end         
             endcase
          end
     end
endmodule
```

In the code above, each state has only one State <= (new state) command.
We only assign the afterDelayState variable when jumping to the ST_DELAY_1S "subroutine" so we know where to go back to.
I took out the `defines to make all assignments more explicit.
One side recommendation is to install VSCode and iverilog so that you can do syntax checking, auto-formatting and compile checking inside the editor.  This quickly helped me clean things up.